# How can I declare an array from the size of a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to copy a vector into an array however I don't know how to declare the array from the size of the vector.

Code:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> ivec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    constexpr size_t size = ivec.size();
    int arr[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i)
        arr[i] = ivec[i];
    for(size_t i : arr)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I think this won't compile because `ivec.size()` can't be a constant expression (though I'm not sure if this is the case). In which case how could I do this without having to manually enter the number of elements?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you think that array is the right thing to do? Arrays need to be dimensioned at compile time. Apart from VLAs, if your compiler supports them. But you don't want to use a VLA. Much easier to declare the array, and copy that into the vector. And you for sure won't need to `for` loop to do the copy!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry I should have added that this is an exercise (3.42) in C++ Primer book

Comment: "I think this won't compile...though I'm not sure if this is the case"  I'll bet a compiler could settle this debate!

Comment: @BrianCain Haha! I know it won't compile but I'm not sure if the constexpr is the case why

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Arrays need not be "dimensioned at compile time", see my answer, and see if I missed something.  Note that once set, the array cannot change size, so I do not refer to variable length arrays.  This also seems to be one instance where arrays have an advantage over `std::array`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thnaks, saw this reffered to as "array of runtime bound", so thought VLA was different. And, I just found that this has been voted down - so it will be implemention specific :(  Editted my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now `std::vector` `size()` is not a `constexpr`, so you cannot use it in `constexpr`essions. As a result, you can try using the `new` keyword for dynamically sized arrays, but that would be pointless, as you're already using a vector.

```
vector<int> vi = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int* arr = new int[vi.size()];
std::copy(vi.begin(), vi.end(), arr);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vi.size(); i++)
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
delete[] arr;
```

**Note:**: You can use `std::begin()` with the second example because `arr[]` is an array but not with the first example because `arr*` is a pointer. However, `std::copy()` accepts both, so it should be fine.

`initializer_list`s can be used in `constexpr`essions:

```
constexpr initializer_list<int> il = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int arr[il.size()];
std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), std::begin(arr));
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < il.size(); i++)
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible to copy a vector into array, because, a usual array is `constexpr`, while vector size is not, it is of dynamic size. There are also dynamic arrays supported by some compilers, but then again, there size is never `constexpr`.
I guess, you need just to use vector.

Comment: Huh! The exercise says "Write a program to copy a vector of ints into an array of ints". I guess it was more about the copying rather than initalising the array

Comment: Well, then you should stick with the exercise, see other answers -- `size` of a vector is **not** `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your motivation, but...

```
int main() {
    vector<int> ivec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    constexpr size_t size = ivec.size();
    int* arr = (int*)malloc( sizeof( int * size ) );
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i)
        arr[i] = ivec[i];
    for(size_t i : arr)
        cout << i << endl;
    free( arr );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile. `ivec.size()` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Also, use `new/delete` instead of `malloc/free` OP tagged C++.

Comment: Agreed that new[] and delete[] should be used - it's a bad habit I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid

```
constexpr size_t size = ivec.size();
int arr[size];
```

and do it like this

```
size_t size = ivec.size();
int* arr = new int[size];
```

and then you handle it like the constantly allocated array. Read more about dynamically allocated arrays.
and don't forget to

```
delete[] array;
```

Comment: `new int(size)` allocates one int with the value of `size`.  Maybe you meant `new int[size]`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I haven't actually seen a difference between (size) and [size]. g++ compile this allocation as an array's one.

Comment: Just because it didn't crash doesn't mean it was correct.  Run it in the debugger and trace into which `operator new` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory, because as you have said vector size is not a constant:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> ivec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    size_t size = ivec.size();
    int *arr = new int[size]; // allocate memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i)
        arr[i] = ivec[i];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << i << endl;
    delete [] arr;  // release memory
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get hold of the number of the elements in an initializer list yielding a `constexpr`. The only way I'm aware of doing this is to use

```
#include <cstddef>
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size(T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

int main() {
    int vec[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    constexpr std::size_t s = size(vec);

    int array[s];
    std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), array);
}
```

If you really need to use a `std::vector<T>` as source, you'll need to allocate memory, probably using `std::vector<T>` in the first place! If you want to allocate the memory yourself you'd use it something like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[vec.size()]);
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), array.get());
```

The use of `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` makes sure that the allocated memory is released automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A `constexpr` is a *Constant Expression* which is an expression that is evaluated at compile-time.  That it is known at compile-time is a fundamental trait of a `constexpr`.

Given this, you can see how it makes no sense to try to construct a non-dynamically-allocated C-style array at run time when the number of elements will only be known at run-time.   The two ideas are orthogonal.

From a technical standpoint, you cannot initialize a `constexpr` from a non-constant-expression.  `vector::size()` is non-`constexpr`, so as you suspect, it is not only not compilable, but it is also not logical from a design standpoint to try to construct a `constexpr` from it:

```
constexpr size_t size = ivec.size(); // NO GOOD!
```

All this being said, it's *very* rare to need to construct a C-style array from `vector`.  You're already doing the **Right Thing** by using `vector` in the first place.  Don't mess it all up now by copying it to a crappy array.

A `vector` is guaranteed to have contigious storage.  What this means is you can use it just like a C-style array in most cases.  All you need to do is pass the address (or reference) to the first element in the `vector` to whatever is expecting a C-style array and it will work just fine.

```
void AincentApiFunction (int* array, size_t sizeofArray);

int main()
{
  std::vector <int> v;
  // ...

  AincentApiFunction (&v[0], v.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 arrays may declared as runtime bound on the stack:
(Note: this is only per the latest available draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf and will likely not be standard, but g++ with `-std=c++11` will allow it

Note that is is not constexpression:

8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array]

*D1 [ expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt*

Example from the standard:

```
void f(unsigned int n) {
    int a[n]; // type of a is “array of runtime bound of int”
}
```

So all you need to do is **remove** constexpr:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> ivec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    size_t size = ivec.size();                  // this is fine
    int arr[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i)
        arr[i] = ivec[i];
    for(size_t i : arr)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your compiler may or may not allow this, so depends on how strictly standard you need to be